# How can I access a Google Home devices screen dimensions?

Tags: actions-on-google

I am trying to add image views for my Google action, however the images I have supplied do not always fit the screen. I noticed that the  [image reference](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/webhook/reference/rest/Shared.Types/Image) says I can supply a height and width in pixels - however I need to know what their screen dimensions are to make it fit! Is there a way I can access this?

Here is my current implementation:

```
'use strict';

const { dialogflow } = require("actions-on-google");
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const app = dialogflow();

app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', (conv) => {

  conv.ask("testing....");
  conv.ask(
    new Image({
      url: 'https://myurl.com/someimage.jpg',
      alt: 'some image',
      // width: NEED THIS VALUE
      // height: NEED THIS VALUE
    })
  );
  conv.ask("bla bla bla. ");
});

exports.yourAction = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: There is no method of getting the screen resolution for a conversational action.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way of getting the screen dimensions for the device.

You can set the image to a reasonable size through device testing then use [`ImageDisplayOptions`](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/df-asdk/rich-responses#optional) to adjust the behavior of the image resizing for different screen sizes.